# How to create instance of control from DataTemplate in code behind

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, datatemplate, code-behind

How can i create the instance of control described by `DataTemplate` in code behind? I found a template in resource dictionary:

```
var template = resourceDictionary["Button"] as DataTemplate;
```

Now i want to create a control by using `DataTemplate`, but how?

```
var control = template.[MakeControl]?
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Call `LoadContent()` and cast the result:

```
var template = resourceDictionary["Button"] as DataTemplate;
var control = template.LoadContent() as Button;
```

---

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="Button">
    <Button Content="btn" />
</DataTemplate>
```